# ValueError: Element <xpath expr="//button[@name='279']"> cannot be located in parent view

Tags: python, odoo

Why am I getting this error?

> ValueError: Element '' cannot be
>   located in parent view
>
> Error context: View `Add custom forecasted quantities` [view_id: 2030,
>   xml_id: forecasted_qty.forecasted_qty_product_template_only_form_view,
>   model: product.template, parent_id: 362]

(-)
                                    
                                
                                Qty for Sale

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="forecasted_qty_product_normal_form_view">
        <field name="name">Add custom forecasted quantities</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_normal_form_view"/>
        <field name="model">product.product</field>
        <field name="priority">99</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
             <xpath expr="//button[@name='%(stock.action_stock_level_forecast_report_product)d']" position="before">
                 <button name="do_nothing" type="object" attrs="{'invisible':[('type', '!=', 'product')]}"
                        class="oe_stat_button" icon="fa-building-o">
                        <div class="o_field_widget o_stat_info">
                            <span class="o_stat_value"><field name="forecasted_qty" widget="statinfo" nolabel="1"/>
                                <span attrs="{'invisible':[('outgoing_qty', '=', 0),('incoming_qty','=',0)]}">
                                    (-<field name="outgoing_qty" widget="statinfo" nolabel="1"/>)
                                </span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="o_stat_text">Qty for Sale</span>
                        </div>
                    </button>
             </xpath>
          </field>
      </record>
```

Comment: in your module `forecasted_qty` you defined at least two view  `forecasted_qty_product_template_only_form_view` and `forecasted_qty_product_normal_form_view` the code in your question works fine the problem is in the first view the target element is not there, read the message error it telling witch view the XPATH didn't find the target.

Comment: and could you post the code of that view?

Answer (score 1):

Use like below:

```
<xpath expr="//header/button[279]" pposition="before">
```